# Can't build KAA on OS X

Tags: java, maven, iot, kaa

After running mvn -f kaa/pom.xml clean install -DskipTests

i got:
[Full log](http://res.cloudinary.com/faradey27/raw/upload/v1479120734/Projects_mvn_-f_kaa_2Fpom_ee84gg.txt)

My environment:

> kaa git:(master) mvn -v
>   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -Xms4096m
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=2048m; support was removed in 8.0
>   Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T18:41:47+02:00)
>   Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec
>   Java version: 1.8.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>   Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
>   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
>   OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

[Full log](http://res.cloudinary.com/faradey27/raw/upload/v1479120734/Projects_mvn_-f_kaa_2Fpom_ee84gg.txt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it does not depend on OS. If your look at the section above the final build status of each module, you will see error message which will give you complete understanding of what is going wrong:

```
[ERROR] Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -Xms4096m
[ERROR] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=2048m; support was removed in 8.0
[INFO] Error occurred during initialization of VM
[INFO] Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size
```

So, one of the way to fix this problem is to run next command in your terminal:

```
$ unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
```

But note that in such case you will remove `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` only from current shell session. To completely remove it try to find this variable in `.bashrc` or `.profile` files in your home directory and remove it from there.